# Android: how to make custom app info menu

Tags: android, settings, android-applicationinfo, info

I have an android application which works with `httppost` methods. It's a tablet application and i am using Android Version 4.0.4. I want to chance post url informaion from:
Settings > Applications > MyApp's App Info 
menu.
How can i create new settings button on that menu? In the other word i want to make Application Settings like in iOS.

Note: I want to use settings like `Dolphin Browser`. There is a Manage space option in App Info tap. I want to create or customize like that one.

Answer (score 1):

The Manage space button that you see can't be customized. It's either clear data or Manage space, thats it.

To get the `Manage space` button instead of `clear data` use the following attribute in the application tag of your Manifest file:

```
 android:manageSpaceActivity="com.example.yourpackage.YourAnyActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

See [docs of Settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

If you want to provide settings for your app, you should use Android's [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) APIs to build an interface that's consistent with the user experience in other Android apps (including the system settings).

[image]

A few of the most common preferences are:

- CheckBoxPreference
- ListPreference
- EditTextPreference